# Set UITabBarItem image/icon in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am creating a custom view in Interface Builder. The view has a `UITabBar` at the bottom. I want to set the icon of each "button" to one of the system provided icons that are in [Apple's UITabBarItem Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006928-CH3-SW2).

I tried to do this by typing in 'UITabBarSystemItemRecents' in the 'Image' field found at *Inspector -> Attributes inspector -> Bar Item -> Image*. Before this, I first selected the `UITabBar` and then the `UITabBarItem` I wanted the image for.

This did not work however, I just get a square instead. I did some searching and found that you can set the icon programmatically, but I want to do as much as possible of the view in Interface Builder.

I use Xcode 5.0.2 and develop for iOS 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: The full credit should go to **null** and **akash**. They contributed by answering half of the question each.*

You can't have one of the icons from Apple that are avaible directly in Interface Builder  **and** have a custom title. Instead, you must download the icon you want to use (Apple-looking icons are avaible at [icons8](http://icons8.com/free-ios-7-icons-in-vector/)), add it to the project resources and then pick it from the dropdown menu at *Inspector -> Attributes inspector -> Bar Item -> Image*.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily set it in Attributes inspector on right panel..Set image as shown below

[image]

If you drag and drop images in you file.access it from media library:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Apple's Recent image then you need to select it from inspector -> Tab Bar Item -> Identifier.

Alternatively you can add the image you want to your app and **pick** it from inspector -> Bar Item -> Image.

Note that if you choose the identifier you cannot set the title and vise versa.

Comment: I didn't understand your second suggestion. Do you mean that I should add an image to the project resources first, and then pick it in the dropdown menu?

Comment: Exactly, or you can add it to the image asset.

Comment: But how do I get the system provided icon there?

Comment: You can't, but you can get any icon from the web.

Comment: OK. Do you know a way to get one of the system provided icons? I obviously want them as high-res as possible. A screenshot on Apple's website isn't good enough. :)

Comment: I don't know if it ok for apple to do that, because even if you find these images, you may get your app rejected :S, there are tons of free ios7 icons on the web, use them.

Comment: If you want to purchase apple icons. try glyphish.com

Comment: @akash bro be aware that these are not Apples' icons, maybe close but not the same ;).

Comment: @null the site says the glyphish is used by apple.

Comment: @akash come on this is total misleading!!! Apple dudes wont buy their icons for 25 bucks, where did you see this?!

Comment: Look at the bottom of their page. I agree its unbelievable.

Comment: @akash I created a wiki post because you two answered half the question each! :)